# Determining the radius of a circle tangent to two identical circles and a straight line tangent to all three.

Tags: geometry

Here is a badly drawn MS Paint representation of the problem:

[image]

We have two circles, shown in red, each with radius $R$ and tangent to one another. A straight line, shown in purple, is drawn tangent to both red circles. We then draw a blue circle tangent to both red circles and the purple line. What is the radius of the blue circle, in terms of $R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the radius $r$. Then by Pythagorean Theorem $$R^2+(R-r)^2=(R+r)^2$$ so $$R^2=4rR\implies r={R\over 4}$$

Comment: Thank you! It felt like there was a simple Pythagorean Theorem argument lurking in there but I just couldn't see it.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the answer?
How is it that by the Pythagorean Theorem you arrive at
$R^2+(R−r)^2=(R+r)^2$ ?

Comment: @Angel Draw a right triangle with hypotenuse between the centers of a red circle and the blue circle, and with the point of intersection of the two red circles as its third vertex.